# How do I find out what process is putting my machine to sleep?

Tags: power-management, sleep

My laptop is going to sleep after about 10 minutes of inactivity, and I don't know why. I verified the standard power options, are they're not set to put my machine to sleep.

[image]

Here is grep's output for 'power'.

```
~$ ps aux | grep [p]ower
a         2554  0.0  0.0 274276  3332 ?        Sl   07:30   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
root      2575  0.0  0.0 231156  4560 ?        Sl   07:30   0:00 /usr/lib/upowe /upowerd
a        10604  0.0  0.6 1159700 53516 ?       Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-control-center.real power
```

Grep'ing for 'screen' shows no useful results as well.

How do I find out which process is putting my computer to sleep?

Comment: What's the distro? Take a look in either `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` for some messaging about it. Also a look in `dmesg`.

Comment: Maybe is not suspending but blanking the screen. Check the screen brightness configuration, at the bottom of your capture.

Comment: It's definitely going to sleep because the power button blinks and the internet becomes disconnected.

Comment: Try to kill all screensavers (`ps ax | grep saver`)